# How trigger kingcomposer css animation through jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

Currently I'm working on one wordpress custom theme and we use the kingcomposer builder for content.

Every post is one slider and every kingcomposer section is one slide. When the post is loaded and on the first slide kingcomposer css animations is working but when I go to the next slide animations not activate.

This is HTML generated by kingcomposer builder:

```
<div id="livingmemorial" class="lm-story-section fullpage-wrapper" style="height: 100%; position: relative; touch-action: none; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
<section data-kc-fullheight="middle-content" class="kc-elm kc-css-17041 section kc_row fp-section active fp-table fp-completely" data-fp-styles="null" style="height: 657px;">
    <div class="fp-tableCell" style="height: 657px;">
        <div class="kc-row-container  kc-container  intro">
            <div class="kc-wrap-columns">
                <div class="kc-elm kc-css-139517 kc_col-sm-12 kc_column kc_col-sm-12">
                    <div class="kc-col-container">
                        <div class="kc-elm kc-css-605939 kc_text_block kc-pc-loaded">
                            <h1 style="color: #fff;font-size:72px">Lorem ipsum</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="kc-elm kc-css-834586 kc_text_block kc-pc-loaded" style="">
                            <h3 style="color: #fff;font-size:32px;"><em>Dolore sit amet</em></h3>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section data-kc-fullheight="middle-content" class="kc-elm kc-css-521807 section kc_row fp-section fp-table" data-fp-styles="null" style="height: 657px;">
    <div class="fp-tableCell" style="height: 657px;">
        <div class="kc-row-container  kc-container  intro">
            <div class="kc-wrap-columns">
                <div class="kc-elm kc-css-705768 kc_col-sm-5 kc_column kc_col-sm-5">
                    <div class="kc-col-container">
                        <div class="kc-elm kc-css-655426 kc-animated kc-animate-eff-fadeInUp kc_text_block">
                            <h3 style="text-align: left; color: #fff; font-size: 32px;">Chapter 1</h3>
                        </div>
                        <div class="kc-elm kc-css-28636 kc-animated kc-animate-eff-fadeInUp kc-animate-delay-200 kc_text_block">
                            <h1 style="text-align: left; color: #fff; font-size: 72px;">Lorem ipsum</h1>
                        </div>
                        <div class="kc-elm kc-css-600603 kc-animated kc-animate-eff-fadeInUp kc-animate-delay-400 kc_text_block">
                            <p style="text-align: left; color: #fff; font-size: 21px; line-height: 1.3em;">Lorem ipsum dolore sit amet.</p>                                
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="kc-elm kc-css-408249 kc_col-sm-7 kc_column kc_col-sm-7">
                    <div class="kc-col-container"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

This is JS code for slider:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myFullpage = new fullpage('#livingmemorial', {
        scrollOverflow: true
    });
</script>
```

And here is kingcomposer JS : [Here](http://nurgradacac.ba/wp-content/plugins/kingcomposer/assets/frontend/js/kingcomposer.js?ver=2.9)

And this is slider JS: [Here](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html)

At the end my question is can someone explain me how again trigger the kingcomposer animations when go to next slide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for this problem.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myFullpage = new fullpage('#livingmemorial', {
        scrollOverflow: true,
        afterLoad: function (origin, destination, direction) {
            jQuery('section.active .kc-animated').each(function (index) {
                var clazz = jQuery(this).get(0).className, delay = 0, speed = '2s', timeout = 0;

                if (clazz.indexOf('kc-animate-delay-') > -1) {
                    delay = clazz.split('kc-animate-delay-')[1].split(' ')[0];

                    jQuery(this).css({'animation-delay': delay + 'ms'});
                    jQuery(this).removeClass('kc-animate-delay-' + delay);

                    timeout += parseInt(delay);
                }

                if (clazz.indexOf('kc-animate-speed-') > -1) {
                    speed = clazz.split('kc-animate-speed-')[1].split(' ')[0];

                    jQuery(this).css({'animation-duration': speed});
                    jQuery(this).removeClass('kc-animate-speed-' + speed);
                }

                if (clazz.indexOf('kc-animate-eff-') > -1) {
                    var eff = clazz.split('kc-animate-eff-')[1].split(' ')[0];

                    timeout += parseFloat(speed) * 1000;

                    jQuery(this).removeClass('kc-animated').addClass('animated ' + eff);

                    setTimeout(function (eff) {
                        jQuery(this).removeClass('animated kc-animated kc-animate-eff-' + eff + ' ' + eff);
                        jQuery(this).css({'animation-delay': '', 'animation-duration': ''});
                    }, timeout, jQuery(this), eff);
                }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```